# how do I build an association between 2 fields that do not follow any naming convention?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My company has an old website that was built many years ago in PHP. I believe the database schema represents the slow accumulation of requests that were never thought about in a strategic way. Now we are throwing out the PHP code and building the site using Rails. The database schema remains, mostly unchanged.

I'm just getting my head around Rails, so this will be perhaps a simple question.

I have an article table where the data looks like this:

```
id: 1102129
article_type_id: 5
old_article_id: 0
title: Zombie Film Locations
subtitle: Hollywood-inspired survival tips for destinations teeming with the undead
display_date: 0000-00-00
author_id: 29
thumbnail_image_id: 12033473
index_image_id: 12033473
article_image_id: 12033473
is_archived: 0
is_featured: 1
is_published: 1
date_to_show: 2011-10-04 00:00:00
off_the_path: 0
created: 2011-10-04 12:45:07
modified: 2011-10-11 15:33:59
fact_check_date: 0000-00-00 00:00:00
unpublish_date: 0000-00-00
is_qsfeatured: 1
featured_order: 0
```

Second row:

```
id: 1102128
article_type_id: 14
old_article_id: 0
title: Hotel Adagio [id]35677
subtitle: Hotel Adagio
display_date: 2011-09-29
author_id: 0
thumbnail_image_id: NULL
index_image_id: NULL
article_image_id: NULL
is_archived: 0
is_featured: 0
is_published: 1
date_to_show: 2011-09-29 12:50:38
off_the_path: 0
created: 2011-09-29 12:50:38
modified: 2011-09-29 12:50:38
fact_check_date: NULL
unpublish_date: NULL
is_qsfeatured: 0
featured_order: NULL
```

The image data looks like:

```
id: 6722
old_id: 0
type: Index
association_type: TopTen
association_id: 1102129
position: 0
copyright: AMC
caption: The Walking Dead portrays an abandoned, corpse-ridden downtown Atlanta, one of 10 zombie film locations we've scouted out to help you survive (and hide) should the dead rise.
alt_text: Zombie film locations
url: photos/index-TopTens/walkingdeadindex.jpg
_url: 
name: index
published: 0
description:
```

Second row:

```
id: 6723
old_id: 0
type: Thumbnail
association_type: TopTen
association_id: 1102129
position: 0
copyright: AMC
caption: The Walking Dead portrays an abandoned, corpse-ridden downtown Atlanta, one of 10 zombie film locations we've scouted out to help you survive (and hide) should the dead rise.
alt_text: Zombie film locations
url: photos/thumb-TopTens/walkingdeadthumb.jpg
_url: 
name: thumbnail
published: 0
description:
```

The association_id in the images table is the id of the article, though there is no foreign key specified in the database.

How do I get all the images when I get the article?

Right now in the controller I do:

```
@articles = Article.where(:article_type_id => 5).order("id DESC").limit(5)
```

In the view I do stuff like:

```
<%= article.title %>
```

But how can I reference the images, from the article model?

To make this more complicated, the images are polymorphic, so I can not simply create a foreign key from images to articles. Images also sometimes get mapped to "travel_guides" and "slideshows", which are 2 other tables we have.

UPDATE:

Changed Article so now it has:

has_many :images, :foreign_key => 'association_id'

Changed my controller code to:

```
@articles = Article.where(:article_type_id => 5).order("id DESC").limit(5).joins(:images)
```

But in my view I do:

<%= article.images.url %>

and I get "no method url" errors.

I was doing:

<%= article.image.url %>

without the "s" on images, and then I got "no method 'image'".

UPDATE:

So, okay, so, on the command line, I run "rails c" to get into the console, and then I run the code that I'm using in my controller:

@articles = Article.where(:article_type_id => 5).order("id DESC").limit(5).joins(:image)

Which gives me:

```
 @articles = Article.where(:article_type_id => 5).order("id DESC").limit(5).joins(:image)
  Article Load (11.5ms)  SELECT `articles`.* FROM `articles` INNER JOIN `images` ON `images`.`association_id` = `articles`.`id` WHERE `articles`.`article_type_id` = 5 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
 => [#<Article id: 1102129, article_type_id: 5, old_article_id: 0, title: "Zombie Film Locations", subtitle: "Hollywood-inspired survival tips for destinations t...", display_date: nil, author_id: 29, thumbnail_image_id: 12033473, index_image_id: 12033473, article_image_id: 12033473, is_archived: false, is_featured: true, is_published: true, date_to_show: "2011-10-04 00:00:00", off_the_path: false, created: "2011-10-04 12:45:07", modified: "2011-10-18 10:44:15", fact_check_date: nil, unpublish_date: nil, is_qsfeatured: true, featured_order: 1, slug: "zombie-film-locations">, #<Article id: 1102129, article_type_id: 5, old_article_id: 0, title: "Zombie Film Locations", subtitle: "Hollywood-inspired survival tips for destinations t...", display_date: nil, author_id: 29, thumbnail_image_id: 12033473, index_image_id: 12033473, article_image_id: 12033473, is_archived: false, is_featured: true, is_published: true, date_to_show: "2011-10-04 00:00:00", off_the_path: false, created: "2011-10-04 12:45:07", modified: "2011-10-18 10:44:15", fact_check_date: nil, unpublish_date: nil, is_qsfeatured: true, featured_order: 1, slug: "zombie-film-locations">, #<Article id: 1102129, article_type_id: 5, old_article_id: 0, title: "Zombie Film Locations", subtitle: "Hollywood-inspired survival tips for destinations t...", display_date: nil, author_id: 29, thumbnail_image_id: 12033473, index_image_id: 12033473, article_image_id: 12033473, is_archived: false, is_featured: true, is_published: true, date_to_show: "2011-10-04 00:00:00", off_the_path: false, created: "2011-10-04 12:45:07", modified: "2011-10-18 10:44:15", fact_check_date: nil, unpublish_date: nil, is_qsfeatured: true, featured_order: 1, slug: "zombie-film-locations">, #<Article id: 1102122, article_type_id: 5, old_article_id: 0, title: "Nude Vacations", subtitle: "These places to get naked around the world make for...", display_date: nil, author_id: 574, thumbnail_image_id: 12024629, index_image_id: 12024629, article_image_id: 12024629, is_archived: false, is_featured: true, is_published: true, date_to_show: "2011-09-23 00:00:00", off_the_path: false, created: "2011-09-23 13:13:41", modified: "2011-10-18 10:44:15", fact_check_date: nil, unpublish_date: nil, is_qsfeatured: true, featured_order: 2, slug: "nude-vacations">, #<Article id: 1102122, article_type_id: 5, old_article_id: 0, title: "Nude Vacations", subtitle: "These places to get naked around the world make for...", display_date: nil, author_id: 574, thumbnail_image_id: 12024629, index_image_id: 12024629, article_image_id: 12024629, is_archived: false, is_featured: true, is_published: true, date_to_show: "2011-09-23 00:00:00", off_the_path: false, created: "2011-09-23 13:13:41", modified: "2011-10-18 10:44:15", fact_check_date: nil, unpublish_date: nil, is_qsfeatured: true, featured_order: 2, slug: "nude-vacations">]
```

So, despite the join, none of the image data shows up.

UPDATE:

Huh, now I see that in that block that I'm getting on the rails console, I see that each article is returning 3 times, I assume because of the JOIN:

Article id: 1102129, article_type_id: 5, old_article_id: 0, title: "Zombie Film Locations", subtitle: "Hollywood-inspired survival tips for destinations t...", display_date: nil, author_id: 29, thumbnail_image_id: 12033473, index_image_id: 12033473, article_image_id: 12033473, is_archived: false, is_featured: true, is_published: true, date_to_show: "2011-10-04 00:00:00", off_the_path: false, created: "2011-10-04 12:45:07", modified: "2011-10-18 10:44:15", fact_check_date: nil, unpublish_date: nil, is_qsfeatured: true, featured_order: 1, slug: "zombie-film-locations">,

## ,

## ,

So I get 3 articles because of the 3 associations with images, yet I do not get the images. This is the worst of both worlds.

It would be easier to do a separate query for the images, really.

UPDATE:

This SQL gives me what I want but I don't seem able to turn this into a Rails query:

```
SELECT articles.title, articles.subtitle, images.url, images.caption 
FROM articles 
JOIN images ON articles.id = images.association_id 
WHERE images.type='Thumbnail' 
ORDER BY articles.id desc 
LIMIT 5 \G
```

UPDATE:

I have not been able to get this to work. I think a Ruby tutor to teach me some basic Ruby and Rails stuff. I am happy to pay. I'm reposting my questions here: http://tutorruby.com/question/show?id=3235

Comment: While you're taking the time to rebuild the site in Rails, have you considered taking the time to rebuild the database schema as well? Just changing column names to be more consistent would go a long way here.

Comment: Yes, there has been a lot of talk about rebuilding the database schema. However, we've been given a deadline of November 30th, which is very ambitious for a website of this scale. The database contains 150 gigs of data, so re-arranging the data is bound to be slow. The management does not want to pay for the extra hosting that would be necessary to give us the capacity to move around the data. And we are short on time. Personally, I'd like to re-do the schema, but I don't think we will be able to.

Comment: The other reality we face is that there is some complex admin software, written in PHP, which will remain untouched, and that admin software expects the database schema to remain the same, so we really are stuck with it. There is no way 2 programmers can undo 6 years of bad decisions in 6 weeks.

Comment: I'm guessing you're getting 3 articles because there are 3 images, and you are specifying that articles should be joined to images.  It's returning exactly what you're asking for.  What are you trying to accomplish with the "joins" clause? Return only articles with images? Or are you trying to eager load your association?  If that latter is what you want, use '.includes(:images)' instead of '.joins(:images)

Comment: Doug R, I should be getting 1 article and 3 images, but instead I'm getting 3 articles and no images. I'm only seeing the image ids, but I want to get all the image data. Thanks for the tip about includes(), I'll try that.

Answer (score 1):

To access the images from an article you need to add an association in the Article class:

```
class Article
  has_many :images, :foreign_key => :association_id
end
```

You mentioned that sometimes images are mapped to travel_guides and slideshows (2 additional tables).  You have to add an association for each table.  So you might do something like:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images, :foreign_key => :association_id
  has_many :travel_guides, :foreign_key => :association_id
  has_many :slideshow_images, :foreign_key => :association_id
end
```

It is generally also a good idea to set up the reverse associations:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article, :foreign_key => :association_id
end
class TravelGuide < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article, :foreign_key => :association_id
end
class SlideshowImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name :slideshows
  belongs_to :article, :foreign_key => :association_id
end
```

Some things to consider:

- I left off the :dependent option in the *has_many* associations.  This is generally not a good idea.  You can set *:depedent => :destroy* so that you can call some cleanup logic in your image classes (to delete the image files).
- If you do not have simple joins, you should consider adding the *:conditions* option to the has_many (or the belongs to).
- Single table inheritance and or polymorhpic associations are both other tools you can use if the above suggestions don't solve all of your problems.

Comment: To clarify: it is not "article" that has many travel_guides or slideshows. Rather, "images" is polymorphic, and can belong to either "article" or "travel_guides" or "slideshows" (or "magazines").

Comment: I can not get this work, sad to say. If I type "rails c" and run the query, I get back an array that has the article info, but not the image info.

Answer (score 1):

When you specify "has_many" in your images association, you are saying that an article has a collection of images, so article.images returns an array.  There is no method 'url' defined on array.  To access the url method, you need to access each individual array member, and call the url on that object. Something like:

```
article.images[0].url
```

or

```
article.images.first.url
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the association in the models. There is a namin convention like you sait but your table doesnt follow that but thats not a problem at all. There are two possible solutions.

1.) You rename the column in the database (what wont work when the app is still in production with PHP)

2.) You specify the association using the :foreign_key parameter like this:

Article:

```
has_many :images, :foreign_key => 'association_id'
```

Picture:

```
belongs_to :article, :foreign_key => 'association_id'
```

But there are some things that you need to attend. You will get some problems naming your table images because theres also an public folder "images" and when you call a picture beginning with a number rails interprets it as an id and trys to fetch an Image instance from the database instead of delivering the image.

Secound problem might get that thers a field called "association_type" which suggestes that thers a polymorphy association. YOu might rename this too when you switch to rails.

Comment: I don't think I can do: belongs_to :article, :foreign_key => 'association_id'  because "images" has polymorphic associations.

Comment: Assume that images is not polymorphic and I add the code you have suggested above, so then I could get the url with article.image.url ?

Comment: Possibly I can use belongs_to with a "condition", as in belongs_to :article, :foreign_key => 'association_id', :condition => "association_type = 'top_ten'" . But could I have multiple conditions?  when association_type is 'magazine' then I need belongs_to to equal 'magazine'.

Answer (score 0):

```
articles = Article.includes(:images).where(:article_type_id => 5, :images => { :image_type => 'Thumbnail' }).order('articles.id DESC').limit(5) #no database query is fired yet by rails
article = articles.first # Here we fire the first query, and this query also fetches the image of the article 
article.images.first #again fires no query but returns the first image of the article
```

There is another case where you should fire db query to fetch only one image from the database. 
Then you should do something like,

```
articles = Article.where(:article_type_id => 5).order("id DESC").limit(5) #again fires no db query
article = articles.first #fires db query to get first article
image = article.images.first #fires query for only first image of the article
```

First method is efficient if you have less number of images per article, but second method is efficient if there is large number of images per article

Now your rails query for the sql posted above,

```
SELECT articles.title, articles.subtitle, images.url, images.caption 
FROM articles 
JOIN images ON articles.id = images.association_id 
WHERE images.type='Thumbnail' 
ORDER BY articles.id desc 
LIMIT 5
articles = Article.joins(:images).select("articles.title, articles.subtitle, images.url, images.caption").where("images.type = 'Thumbnail'").order("articles.id DESC").limit(5)
article = articles.first 
first_image = article.images.first
```